# Как поставить label над input

Tags: html, css

Привет всем возникла задача поставить лейбы над инпутами
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

дело в том что инпуты я разметил внутри form который имеет класс flex потому что надо делить пространсто поровну в форме надо решить задачу чтобы было валидно по валидатору

Comment: А вы хоть что то пробывали? или нужно задачу решить за вас?

Comment: Могу предложить костыльный метод, заключив их в дивы и задать ширину 100% от родителя, при этом родитель нужной ширины... но опять же, я не вижу полного вида

Comment: @MaykalAliyev , `<label><span>Начинка</span><input type="text" /></label>`

Comment: Для решения вашего вопроса необходимо выкладывать **код**.